# How to duplicate and rename a file when folder content changes - Linux or php script?

Tags: php, csv, cron, export, file-rename

I'm exporting .csv file when a new order is made on my site running under prestashop. The site is hosted in a Plesk VM and I need to duplicate the .csv file of the order and rename it to .txt when the .csv is exported. I need to do this operation to connect the .csv with an ERP software.
I don't know how to exactly solve this. My options are:

- Create a php script (but I need to store somewhere the folder changes history in order to compare)
- Create a linux script (no idea how to do)
- Create a cron task.

Comment: Either of the first two would be fine. Cron could work if you want it scheduled, but it still needs to then execute one of the first two in order to actually do anything useful - Cron just a scheduler, it's not equivalent to PHP or shell script. To me it would surely make most sense to just do this in the same script which generates the csv file to begin with

Comment: Done with PHP modifying the script that generates the csv. Thanks :D